# How can I change the default terminal in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lua

I have tried adding this line to the init.lua but it doesn't work and I don't understand the syntax:

```
local g:terminal_emulator="powershell"
```

I get an error upon running the `source` command: it says `unexpected symbol near :`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua the syntax is slightly different.

I would do:

```
vim.g.terminal_emulator='powershell'
```

Or:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_var('terminal_emulator', 'powershell')
```

Comment: Now good luck to me finding out what is the exacting thing I should write in place of 'powershell' :(

Comment: Is this for bang commands? Because it doesn't  seem to work. I always get 'an unknonwn element was received' error

Comment: The `shell` option is used to create the terminal in which the `:!` command run. See the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure the `:terminal` command you have to change the `'shell'` setting instead.

In Lua you can do with

```
vim.opt.shell = 'powershell.exe'
```